# I want to implement an upload form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux, rxjs

My upload form needs to be able to select multiple files, show the upload progress, and show the files uploaded below the upload button, user will be able to delete the upload displayed also. I know there are libraries to execute this, point me in the direction of good ones that i can manipulate the css or provide useful links on how to build from scratch. Thank you

Comment: https://openbase.com/js/@dropzone-ui/react

Comment: how do i customize the css of the upload UI, i don't want mine looking like that and also want the upload to show outside the upload UI

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the file input and trigger the upload with the button or something.

```js
const addFile = () => {
   document.getElementById('fileElement').click()
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="fileElement" style="display:none">
<button onclick="addFile"></button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I figured it out already